# How to correctly do a do_action/add_action with a plugin class in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I think the problem is that there are too many people trying to answer a question, such as here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48085/add-action-reference-a-class

In my case I am using a do_action in my themes template

Which is best....

```
class mytheme_do_header_content{ 

    public function __construct() {

         add_action( 'mytheme_do_header', array( $this, 'mytheme_do_header_content_make' ) );

    }

    function mytheme_do_header_content_make(){

    //some code goes here
    }

    public function __destruct() {

    }
}
new mytheme_do_header_content();
```

or this

```
class mytheme_do_header_content{ 

    public function __construct() {

        //some code goes here
    }

    public function __destruct() {

    }
}
add_action( 'mytheme_do_header', array( $this, 'mytheme_do_header_content_make' ) );
```

or something else like not bothering with a class at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first example is best. You reach the same outcome but in the first example all your hooks are contained within your class (encapsulation).

There wouldn't be any reason to add those hooks outside the class instead.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29

Comment: Thanks for that.

Also as a sub question would you recommend having multiple add_actions within the same __construct or would it be better to have a separate class for each one?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what you consider best. If you write your Wordpress plugin in form of a class, it perhaps is best that one (static) method of the class knows how it instantiates itself. That method can also cover registration of the plugin:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', array('mytheme_do_header_content', 'init'), 5);

class mytheme_do_header_content
{
    static function init() {
        $plugin = new self();
        add_action('mytheme_do_header', array($plugin, 'mytheme_do_header_content_make'));         
    } 

    function mytheme_do_header_content_make() {
        //some code goes here
    }
}
```

This variant has the benefit

- a) that the non-static code won't need to care about instantiation and registration. It depends a bit how elaborated your plugin is until this has really an effect on your codes design, but it's not that wrong to separate object instantiation from the usage.
- and b) that it will only be instantiated when plugins are loaded. This is because the plugins `::init` method is called on the `plugins_loaded`  hook. This benefits from the static plugin factory method.

Comment: In my case I was talking about a custom theme but thanks anyhow I will remember this when making a plugin

Comment: For themes you've got similar hooks to initialize the code, the same principles apply.